# How to deploy an Azure Logic App using VS that calls a disabled (non running) Azure Function?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

How to deploy an Azure Logic App using VS that calls a disabled (non running) Azure Function?

When I have the Azure Function running the deployment of the Azure Logic App from VS 2017 succeeds and everything is awesome.

When I stop the Azure Function from running the deployment of the Azure Logic App fails with the following error:

```
11:54:05 - Template deployment returned the following errors:
11:54:05 - 11:54:04 AM - Resource Microsoft.Logic/workflows '[CONFIDENTIAL STRING...]' failed with message '{
11:54:05 -   "error": {
11:54:05 -     "code": "ListFunctionKeysFailed",
11:54:05 -     "message": "Request to obtain the keys for function '/subscriptions/[CONFIDENTIAL STRING...] failed. Error details: 'System.InvalidOperationException: Runtime keys are stored on blob storage. This API doesn't support this configuration. Please change Environment variable AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType value to 'Files'. For more info, visit https://aka.ms/funcsecrets\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.<GetKeyObjectFromFile>d__9`1.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Functions\\FunctionManager.cs:line 141\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.<GetFunctionSecretsAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Functions\\FunctionManager.cs:line 220\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Functions.FunctionController.<GetSecrets>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Functions\\FunctionController.cs:line 141'."
11:54:05 -   }
11:54:05 - }'
11:54:05 - 11:54:04 AM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
11:54:05 - 11:54:04 AM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
11:54:05 - 
11:54:05 - 
11:54:05 - Deploying template using PowerShell script failed.
11:54:05 - Tell us about your experience at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691202
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and get the same error, then I test with Azure Portal to deploy it, this time I get the detailed error message.

[image]

This is because the default setting is blob even it's not shown in Application Settings, so you could  change Environment variable `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType` value to `Files`.

[image]

After this you will be able to upload the logic app with stopped function in VS.

Comment: yeah super helpful... I need to read more about the security ramifications of what setting it to files implies before I accept it as best... I haven't had time to circle back on this issue... but one major outstanding learning I need is Key Vault... apparently that is related to this... sorry for vague reply ... just have to do more research on Key Vault and if Files setting as you mention has security ramifications

Comment: @John Drinane,About the details you could find [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/7bf1b869f101bbec29035bb39ebc71365a4b5afb/Kudu.Core/Functions/FunctionManager.cs#L134), and  about the AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType description you could find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobssecretstoragetype).

Comment: I tested your suggestion and it at least got the minor toy change through to deployment. I don't totally understand what all is stored in files vs blob at this point, but that is my next step. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the default powershell script in visual studio?  Try adding an http binding to your function and then call it from the script to wake it up.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Yes that is how I was testing things